# Parse HTTP Accept Header

Tags: javascript, http

I would like to parse an HTTP Accept Header in javascript, is anyone aware of an existing component that does so?

Comment: You can find some information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: @Quentin: It is a string that is formed like an accept header. The source is not relevant (in this case it's provided by an external script). Basically I want to parse a string formatted like an accept header and return a list of preferred content types ordered by preferential level.

Comment: @user973254 thanks but the answers in that thread are oriented towards the language part of the Accept Header. I need to parse it for content type preferences.

Comment: There's no difference between Accept-Language and Accept except one has ISO language codes and one has content-types. You can use the same algorithm for both.

Comment: @Quentin, true. Exactly why I'm asking this question, is anyone aware of an existing component that does so?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a standards based version of this in JavaScript, it is used by CouchDB, you can use it too:

http://code.google.com/p/mimeparse/source/browse/trunk/mimeparse.js